# LibreOffice Calc: how to convert minutes into decimal hours

Tags: libreoffice-calc, time

I have the value `0:15:00` h:mm:ss - I'd like to get the value `0,25` hours - how can this be done? I tried simply dividing `0:15:00` by 60 but that didn't return what's expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Date_%26_Time_functions#Date_and_Time_overview) says:

> Times are represented as a fraction of a day - for example 0.5 is half
> a day, or 12 hours, or 12 noon; 0.25 is a quarter of a day, or 6 am.
> Thus 39441.25 represents 6am on 25Dec07.

So, the clue is to multiply the `date-time serial number` with 24, as 24 (hours) are one day:

The `date-time serial number` of 00:15:00 is 0,0104166666666667, multiplied with 24 = 0.25. You don't need to transform the time value to a `date-time serial number`, just multiply `00:15:00` with `24`.

Subtractions and other calculations should work *without conversion*, if the correct number format is used:

[image: Subtraction of Time Values in LibreOffice Calc]

Comment: it shows wrong value if I have 13:25 by calculating difference: 02:05
 - 12:40 . 13:25 * 24 = 10 according to it :( same on google sheets.

Comment: @Darius.V: For a HH:MM:SS format, you should have `02:05:00` instead of `02:05`, same for `12:40`. Please check both your input values as well as your cell format. I've just tested with LO 7.6. If this doesn't fit your issue, please open a separate, new question.

Comment: Both the subtraction as well as the conversion of the date-time serial number depend on the number format. Thus, `13:25:00` (formatted as Time value), multiplied with 24 should yield `13,4166666666667` (which does in current LO).